# update yaml with string without single quotes, in c#

Tags: c#, string, yaml

I have a yaml file (under /etc/netplan)

I would like to update the IP address inside it,
according to what the user enters in the application.

When I update "addresses" such as "100.100.100.100" everything works fine,
But I need the value to be inside [], and when I try to update [100.100.100.100], single quotes are added to me.

How can this be avoided?

Thanks

```
    string netplanDirectory = "/etc/netplan"
    var yamlFiles = Directory.GetFiles(netplanDirectory, "*.yaml");
    if (yamlFiles.Length == 0) return false;

    string filePath = yamlFiles[0];
    var yaml = new YamlStream();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        yaml.Load(reader);
    }

    var rootNode = (YamlMappingNode)yaml.Documents[0].RootNode;

    if (rootNode is YamlMappingNode mappingNode)
    {
        if (mappingNode.Children.TryGetValue("network", out var networkNode) && networkNode is YamlMappingNode networkMappingNode)
        {
            if (networkMappingNode.Children.TryGetValue("ethernets", out var ethernetsNode) && ethernetsNode is YamlMappingNode ethernetsMappingNode)
            {
                if (ethernetsMappingNode.Children.TryGetValue(ethernetKey, out var ethernetEntry) && ethernetEntry is YamlMappingNode ethernetNode)
                {
                    if (ethernetNode.Children.ContainsKey("addresses"))
                    {
                        ethernetNode.Children["addresses"] = new YamlScalarNode(addressIp) { Style = YamlDotNet.Core.ScalarStyle.Plain  };


                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
                        {
                            yaml.Save(writer, false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
     }
}
```